# Sequelize searches for field instead of variable

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm new to Sequelize, built a query that looks like this:

```
router.get("/", async (req,res) => {
    try {
        ...
            let filter = req.body.filter || "favorites";
            let filter_value = req.body.filter_value || false;

            let results = await Promise.all([ 
                await models.bookmark.findAll({
                ...,
                    where: {
                        filter:filter_value
                    }
                })              
            ])

            ...
})
```

Problem is, it sees 'filter' as a field/attribute, and uses it for the search, rather than its value 'favorites'. Can anything be done about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [] to use a prop value instead of its name:

```
where: {
  [filter]: filter_value
}
```